# How to get the text from SafariViewController to our application swift?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, sfsafariviewcontroller

In my application, we are using Segpay for payment there is no proper SDK to integrate, then we make the URL from backed and open that in `SafariViewController`.

When the user completes the payment successfully we need to bring to a user into the home page, how to we know status is a success from `SafariViewController`.

I got a response from the backend on `SafariViewController` like this on webview page: [image]

Answer (score -1):

Instead of safari you can use `WKWebview` like below.

Create a property of `WKWebView`

```
private var webView: WKWebView!
```

Initialise webview as follow in `viewDidLoad` method...

```
let jScript = "var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"
let wkUScript = WKUserScript(source: jScript, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)
let wkUController = WKUserContentController()
wkUController.addUserScript(wkUScript)

let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webConfiguration.userContentController = wkUController

webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: webConfiguration)
webView.navigationDelegate = self
view.addSubview(webView)
let url = URL(string: "https://...") //set url to load in webview
let req = URLRequest(url: url)
webView.load(req)
```

Implement the following delegate method of `WKWebView`.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('response_success').textContent", completionHandler: { (html, error) in

        if let content = html as? String {
            print(content)

            if content.lowercased().contains("ok") { //here you can place the status coming from server for comparison

               //handle success response
            }
        }
    })
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('response_fail').textContent", completionHandler: { (html, error) in

        if let content = html as? String {
            print(content)

            if content.lowercased().contains("fail") { //here you can place the status coming from server for comparison

               //handle fail response
            }
        }
    })
}
```

> Note: You need to ask your backend team to post data in webview using  tag with id **response_success**, if response is success & **response_fail**, if response is failed.(You can change it as per your requirements)

Comment: did you set the URL to load in webview?

Comment: Why do you need all that javaScript? I think it's better just to parse that Json that you get from Segpay and that's it. Or am I missing anything in the question?

Comment: jscrip is for to cover the webpage to device width.

Answer (score -1):

It is anyone need to use this code.

## For Load URL:

```
 let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
        let myURL = URL(string: "YOUR_URL")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
```

## Delegate Method for handle URL :

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

        if let url = webView.url?.absoluteString{
            if url.contains("success.php"){
                print("SUCCESS CASE")
            }else if url.contains("fail.php"){
                print("FAILURE CASE")
            }
        }
    }
```